# Format number with jQuery Globalize

Tags: jquery, localization, javascript-globalize

I'm trying to automatically format a number with the proper localization with Globalize. When the users inputs a numeric value I need Globalize to read it, parse it in the right format, and then output it in the field where the user has entered it.

I've tried like so:

```
$(document).on('change','.format-me',function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    Globalize.culture("en-US");
    console.log(Globalize.format(value));
});
```

But it is not working, as the logged number looks exactly the same as the one entered by the user.
Why isn't Globalize changing the format as needed?

Comment: Why is there a need to globalize a number? What type of data is the user entering? Currency? Dates? (Just for my information)

Comment: Well because each culture has a different way of displaying even simple float numbers, e.g. 1.000 vs. 1,000. In both cases I mean one thousand, but in certain cultures (mostly european) the second would be read as one, since the comma identifies the decimals.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just realized that using the jquery spinner, there's a very simple way to do what I was trying:

```
$(document).on('change','.check-float',function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).spinner( "value", value );
});
```

When you assign a value to the spinner like so, it automatically format the value accordingly to the culture assigned to the spinner!

Comment: Hey. Any clue how to resolve decimal format for this case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996151/set-decimal-format-in-jquery-globalize

Answer (score 11):

The reason why the logged number looks exactly the same as the one entered is that you are calling `Globalize.format()` with a string argument – it will then simply return its argument, as documented, assuming you are using [Globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) (originally called jQuery Globalize, later made independent of jQuery). The value of an input control in HTML is taken as a string, and to be processed as a number, it needs to be converted, somehow.

In this context, it should be parsed with `Globalize.parseFloat()`, and when logging it, you need to pass e.g. the format parameter `n2` (since for a number, the default format is `i`, which is seldom useful – one of the pitfalls of Globalize.js):

```
$(document).on('change','.format-me',function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    Globalize.culture("en-US");
    var num = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
    if(isNaN(num)) console.log('Parsing failed');
    console.log(Globalize.format(num, "n2"));
});
```

However, I do not quite see the point in logging the number in a localized format. The user enters a number in a localized format, but for any processing (client-side or server-side), it should be stored in an internationalized format. A localized format may then later be used when displaying some results to the user.

Comment: Thank's for the long explanation, very helpful! You are absolutely right about logging the localized version, I was trying to understand how it works, my actual use of the localized string would not be a log output.