# Set decimal format in jQuery Globalize

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimalformat

I would like to set decimals like `#.#` but it shows always like `#.##`

How I can do it for  jQuery Globalize?

Is any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

[Check this link](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=152732)

```
$.format(45678.987, "n1")
```